# return the length of the shortest word(s)

Tags: c#, string, linq

I need help with Simple, given a string of words, return the length of the shortest word(s).

String will never be empty and you do not need to account for different data types.

```
[Test]
public void BasicTests()
{
  Assert.AreEqual(3, Kata.FindShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"));
  Assert.AreEqual(3, Kata.FindShort("turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones"));      
}
```

MY solution that doesn't work. I do not have idea for this sample.

```
public static int FindShort(string s)
{
     String[] arr = s.Split(' ');
     int min = arr.Select(x => x.Length).Min();
     return min;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? It passes both of the test cases.
Code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/b8GGam ; prints 3 3, as it should.

Comment: What are the *counter examples*, please? On which input you have wrong answer?

Comment: Slightly simpler version: `arr.Min(x => x.Length)` btw. The whole thing can be a pretty simple expression-bodied method: `public static int FindShortestLength(string text) => text.Split(' ').Min(word => word.Length);`

Comment: If you have *two* or more spaces in a line, say `"a    b"` you'll get `0`; `String[] arr = s.Split(new char[' ', '\t'], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Now that we have nullable reference types, wouldn't `public static int? FindShortestLength(string? text) => text?.Split(' ').Min(word => word.Length);` be better @JonSkeet -hallowed be thy name- :) 
That would also prevent a possible `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @uTeisT: I would prefer there to be an ArgumentNullException - I see no reason to particularly make it accept a nullable string reference, at least without knowing more context. If you regularly wanted to use it in that situation you *could* do that, but I wouldn't normally do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are looking for *generalized case* (string with *punctuations*, *digits* etc.) then we should come to terms what word is.

If we define word to be a

> sequence of *letters* and *apostrophes*

we can try *regular expressions* in order to `Match` the words:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public static int FindShort(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    return 0; // or throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

  return Regex
    .Matches(value, @"[\p{L}']+") // word is one or more letter or apostroph
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Min(match => match.Value.Length);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
// The shortest word is "four" and the answer is 4
// Your current code returns 1 for "-"  
string test = 
  "1. Testing string (2. тестовая строка - Russian); expected answer - 4 - four";

Console.Write(FindShort(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is it:

in C#:

```
   public static int FindShort(string sentence)
   {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
        {
               return Regex.Split(sentence, @"\s+").OrderBy(x1 => x1.Length).ToList().First().Length;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

in Vb.Net:

```
Public Shared Function FindShort(ByVal sentence As String) As Integer
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence) Then
        Return Regex.Split(sentence, "\s+").OrderBy(Function(x1) x1.Length).ToList().First().Length
    End If

    Return -1
End Function
```